# FFMpeg's stream segmenter

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, aac, transcoding, mpeg2-ts

I'm using FFMpeg to segment a WAV file into mp3s for use in HTTP Live Streaming. 
I'm using this command:

> ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -map 0:0 -f segment
>   -segment_time 10 -segment_list outputlist.m3u8 -segment_format mp3 'output%03d.mp3'

The stream is working, however I'm getting small "gaps" between each mp3 segment. Why is this?

Comment: Are you limited to mp3? AAC generally works WAY better in HLS. The apple engineers I have chatted with in the forums seem to indicate mp3 support is very low priority for them.

Comment: If TS contain multiple programs (TV programs that captured by DVB-T), how can split it? For example I have a TS file that contain football + cooking + cartoon .How can i split this TS file to 3 mpg files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using -segment_format mpegts.

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -map 0:0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list outputlist.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts 'output%03d.mp3'
```

Comment: I just tested : If you keep mp3 extension, it's working well for HLS, but players like VLC are not able to play your mp3 files anymore. An other solution is to keep `-segment_format mpegts` and sepcify m4a as destination format : `output%03d.m4a`. 
You saved my day !